# Evaluating Fourier transform of a Gaussian with FFTW3 and C++

Tags: c++, fftw

I have tried to calculate the Fourier Transform of a Gaussian function by using FFTW3 in C++. Here is the main part of my code

```
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   fftw_plan p;
   complex<double> *in,*out;
   long N=8;

   //allocation of in and the fftw plan called 
   in=(complex<double>*) calloc(N,sizeof(complex<double>));
   p=fftw_plan_dft_1d(N,(fftw_complex*)in,(fftw_complex*)in,FFTW_BACKWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);

   //initialize the array in with the values of a Gaussian function
   gaussianf(in,N);
   //Fourier transform in
   fftw_execute(p);  
   //write the result into a file
   writeft(in,N);
   fftw_destroy_plan(p);
}
```

Since the array has been initialized with the values of a Gaussian, I would expect that the output is also a Gaussian but actually only the envelope has a Gaussian shape. As I show in the data below, where it is possible to see that some negative values have appeared.

```
#input values
#x       real part     imag part

-10     3.72008e-44     0
-7.5    3.72336e-25     0
-5      1.38879e-11     0
-2.5    0.00193045      0
0       1       0
2.5     0.00193045      0
5       1.38879e-11     0
7.5     3.72336e-25     0

#output
#x       real part     imag part
-10     1.00386 0
-7.5    -1.00273        0
-5      1       0
-2.5    -0.99727        0
0       0.996139        0
2.5     -0.99727        0
5       1       0
7.5     -1.00273        0
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you just used the command out of the box as depicted? I am using the same library but I get nonzero imaginary part when transforming real and even data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong in the sense of the C programming or FFTW calls: those are the correct values.   The real part of the FFT of a Gaussian curve does oscillate around zero.  If you plot the *absolute* values, that might look a little more like you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Maybe I am misunderstanding something but if one calculates the FT via the usual integral, one obtains another Gaussian without negative values. Why is it different?

Comment: The integrals are always positive if you're multiplying by `cos(n*theta)` with `theta=0` in the middle (i.e. where the peak of your Gaussian is). But that's not what the DFT assumes:  it assumes `theta=0` at the beginning of the signal.  So now, depending on `n`, there will be a varying phase relationship between the cosine wave and the peak of the Gaussian.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, now it is clear. The questions now is how to calculate numerically a "true" FT using FFTW.

Comment: Just adopt the same convention when composing your input signal: first sample is t=0, second is t=1; last is t=-1, penultimate is t=-2.  I believe fftw has some sort of circular shift function that lets you convert a signal back and forth between this and the t=0-in-the-middle convention (matlab would call it FFTSHIFT).  Even if not, it's a pretty simple routine to program by hand.

Answer (score 0):

These oscillations are expected. In practice, one needs to use a window function to reduce these oscillations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function